# Delete nested in nested JSON file

Tags: python, json

First i know how to read .JSON file, but now i confused how to delete partial nested. As you can see i use `clear()` method to clear nested JSON, why? When i want to use `remove(i)`, it works, but not removing what i want, just make the JSON file got an error
Before

```
{"dump data": [
    {
        "dump detail": [
            {
                "dumper": "MorpKnight",
                "title": "test"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "dump detail": [
            {
                "dumper": "MorpKnight",
                "title": "test 2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

After (The one i want as result)

```
{"dump data": [
    {
        "dump detail": [
            {
                "dumper": "MorpKnight",
                "title": "test"
            }
        ]
    }
```

And this is my code

```
data_name = input("Search data")
with open('config.json', "r+") as file:
        json_load = json.load(file)
        for i in json_load['dump data']:
            for j in i['dump detail']:
                if j['title'] == data_name:
                    i.clear()
                    print("Deleted")
                    return
```

Comment: could you explain some more on what exactly are you trying to remove from the dictionary?

Comment: @goldenotaste i want to store data in my project, and that data can callable when someone want to call it. The user who created the data also can delete the data when data isn't useful anymore. In other words this is data storer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove items from a list while iterating over it, it's a bad idea unless you do it in reverse and it's not efficient nonetheless.

This however should work:

```
import json
data_name = input("Search data")
with open('config.json', "r+") as file:
    json_load = json.load(file)
    new_details = []
    for detail in json_load['dump data']:
        if all(data['title'] != data_name for data in detail['dump detail']):
            new_details.append(detail)
    json_load['dump data'] = new_details
```

I recreate the details list per your specification. You may then save `json_load` back into the file if you wish.

Comment: look at here, i use your code and this worked but it not delete at all [click here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/843485603928735795/967607310052655194/unknown.png)

Answer (score -1):

```
data = {"dump data": [
    {
        "dump detail": [
            {
                "dumper": "MorpKnight",
                "title": "test"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "dump detail": [
            {
                "dumper": "MorpKnight",
                "title": "test 2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}

def clean(data, data_name):
    data_clean = {'dump data': []}
    for i, e in enumerate(data['dump data']):
        if e['dump detail'][0]['title'] != data_name:
            data_clean['dump data'] = e
    return data_clean
data_name = input("Search data: ")
data_clean = clean(data, data_name)
print(data_clean)
```

prints

```
Search data: test 2
{'dump data': [{'dump detail': [{'dumper': 'MorpKnight', 'title': 'test'}]}]}
```

Comment: Don't modify a list while iterating over it

Comment: The OP is searching in all titles, not necessarily the first.

Comment: OP has not made any statement about the inner lists (of dicts with keys "dumper" and "title") to contain more than one element.